# Do something only if no inputs are in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Was wondering if you could help me. I have several inputs on a page with multiple tabs.I would like left + right arrows to change tab but ONLY if no inputs on the page are in focus

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (NO_INPUTS_IN_FOCUS) {
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            // left arrow
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            // right arrow
        }
    }

}
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For your case :**

```
if (!($("input").is(":focus"))) {    
    NO_INPUTS_IN_FOCUS = true;    
}

else {
    NO_INPUTS_IN_FOCUS = false;
}
```

Comment: This works, surprisingly - can be written `NO_INPUTS_IN_FOCUS = !$("input").is(":focus")` - It does not work for textareas and select unless you add those

Comment: Perfect had that except without the is check after -.-, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        tag = target.tagName.toLowerCase();

    if (tag != "input" && tag.indexOf("select") ==-1 && tag != "textarea") {
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            // left arrow
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            // right arrow
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats an interesting way to do it thanks for sharing! I will take the jquery option in this case but i've learnt something new there